# apple calendar api to integrate with node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, icloud, icalendar

i can't find apple calander api to intgerate with my node js backend app so that i can get event data, add event, modify events and all those stuff.

**Please assist if anybody knows about that.**

Answer (score 2):

With nodejs there is a repository on github to handle

> Getting collections of callendars
> https://github.com/MauriceConrad/iCloud-API#calendar
> [Creating](https://github.com/MauriceConrad/iCloud-API#create-event) event callendar

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Apple doesn't allow to integrate anything (Corporate *culture* / Policy) . Check unofficial npm lib for this: https://github.com/MauriceConrad/iCloud-API